# Prevent other versions of jquery from loading on static front page

Tags: jquery, frontpage

[This site](http://www.tempertemper.com.au/test/) is using [cordillera](https://wordpress.org/themes/cordillera/) which calls on `/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2`.

The child theme contains a front-page.php which consists of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<link type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/front-page.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" <?php body_class($class); ?>>
    <div id="front-page">
        <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/tempertemper.jpg" alt="Temper Temper entry image" width="1200" height="800" usemap="#Map" title="Temper Temper Fine Chocolates" border="0" />
        <map name="Map" id="Map">
          <area shape="rect" coords="115,500,637,773" href="http://www.margaretriver.com" alt="Margaret River" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="641,240,857,772" href="/test/shop" alt="Visit our online shop" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="195,186,366,449" href="/test/gallery" alt="Come see our image gallery" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="504,349,622,440" href="/test/contact" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="616,124,890,237" href="/test/about-us" alt="About Temper Temper" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="985,285,1164,488" href="https://www.facebook.com/tempertempermargaretriver" alt="Follow Temper Temper on Facebook" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="859,490,1036,793" href="http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Restaurant_Review-g255367-d7789880-Reviews-Temper_Temper_Fine_Chocolate-Margaret_River_Margaret_River_Region_Western_Austral.html" alt="See our Reviews on Trip Advisor" />
        </map>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'front-page-menu' ) ); ?>
        <p align="center">&copy; Temper Temper 2015</p>
    </div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.rwdImageMaps.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The main image (`div#front-page img`) is responsively sized for screen size <= 960px.

I want to make the image map responsive too, by using [this project](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps). This project relies on jQuery, but doesn't seem to work with jQuery v1.11.2. i.e: Using `/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2` the image map is not responsive. It produces a Chrome code inspector console error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` using `jquery.js?ver=1.11.2`

So I want to try including jQuery v2, but to do so, I must first disable `/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2` from front-page.php.

How do I do this?

Comment: If it is not too much asked, responding on/accepting an answer would for all users helpfull. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am on thin ice but lets try.

Assuming that you already have the correct jquery version(you want to use) downloaded and copied to a folder. 
(The same js folder as the `jquery.rwdImageMaps.js` would be logical imho)

Imho you also can delete folowing code part `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.rwdImageMaps.js"></script>`
from that front-page.php file and load it together with the ('new')jQuery and migrate file into the footer.
*When you do not want that, please delete the 2 lines below `//To load the jquery.rwdImageMaps.js file also into the footer`*

You could use following function.(I assume you downloaded both files, the normal and minified jQeury file), *(use `false,true` to go into footer `false,false` to go into head)*

> Please copy this function in the functions.php (in your child-theme folder)

```
function load_scripts_into_footer() {
    // Only load on front-page.php (else it could brake some?)
    if ( is_front_page() ){

        // Deregister the undesirable jQuery file WP uses itself
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

        // The Version2 jQuery file
        wp_register_script( 'jquery-2.0.0.min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js', array(), false, true ); 
        wp_enqueue_script(  'jquery-2.0.0.min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js', array(), false, true );

        // It is recommend to use jquery-migrate in this case
        wp_enqueue_script(  'jquery-migrate.min', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js', array('jquery-2.0.0.min'), false, true );

        // To load the jquery.rwdImageMaps.js file also into the footer
        wp_register_script( 'jquery.rwdImageMaps', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.rwdImageMaps', array('jquery-2.0.0.min','jquery-migrate.min'), false, true );
        wp_enqueue_script(  'jquery.rwdImageMaps', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.rwdImageMaps', array('jquery-2.0.0.min','jquery-migrate.min'), false, true );
    }
}
// Action hook
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts_into_footer' );
```

I have not tested it but it should work imho. Give it a try I would say.

> - How to use    [deregister](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script)
> - How to    [register](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)
> - How to    [enqueue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)
> - More information about [jQuery
>     2.0](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/)

Comment: `!is_admin()` is a useless check when using `wp_enqueue_scripts`. `wp_enqueue_scripts` only run on front end queries ;-)

Comment: No problem, still, +1 for the answer :-)